# SQL join for filling missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join, cross-apply

I have a table of historical data *(**#Records**)*; at the end of a sproc I need to fill the data against a table of dates (`dbo.MasterDates`). For the following simplified example, I'll simply use **City** as the identifier for a unique series of data.

tempdb.dbo.#Records:

| Date | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-04 | LA | 10.5 |
| 2021-06-04 | NYC | 11.2 |
| 2021-06-05 | LA | 9.2 |
| 2021-06-06 | NYC | 8.1 |

dbo.Dates:

| Date | Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-04 | 2021 | 6 | 4 |
| 2021-06-05 | 2021 | 6 | 5 |
| 2021-06-06 | 2021 | 6 | 6 |

If the data was filtered so there was only one series being retrieved *(i.e., only data for NYC)*, filling would be a simple select from **dbo.Dates** and a `left outer join` on **#Records**. However, I need to fill such that there is a record for each day, for each unique City.

e.g. *(filled records **bolded**)*

| Date | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-04 | LA | 10.5 |
| 2021-06-04 | NYC | 11.2 |
| 2021-06-05 | LA | 9.2 |
| **2021-06-05** | **NYC** | **0.0** |
| **2021-06-06** | **LA** | **0.0** |
| 2021-06-06 | NYC | 8.1 |

My first attempt was to create a version of the **dbo.Dates** with records for each unique city, and then use this to fill the **#Records** table:

```
insert into #FilledDates (Date, City)
select
    dates.Date, City
from Dates d
cross apply
(
    select distinct City from #Records
) r

select
    d.Date, d.City, isnull(r.Value, 0)
from #FilledDates d
left outer join #Records r on r.Date = d.Date and r.City = d.City
```

This works fine; however, given that the actual use case is much more complex, I'm curious if there is a better way to achieve the desired result. The performance is my main concern... It seems like I should be able to combine the cross apply & join steps, however I'm still a bit new to cross apply.

Comment: If you had a Cities table, it would likely be more performant to `CROSS JOIN` to that, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your `#Records` table. `DISTINCT` *can* be an expensive operator.

Comment: @Larnu I wanted to make the example as simple as possible; in the real use-case I store the unique combinations of fields in a separate temp table. I'll look into a cross join, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a projection with all the possible city/date combinations, and then join to that:

```
WITH Projection AS (
    SELECT City, [Date]
    FROM Dates
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Records) c
)
SELECT p.*, coalesce(r.[Value], 0.0) as [Value]
FROM Projection p
LEFT JOIN #Records r ON r.[Date] = p.[Date] AND r.City = p.City
ORDER BY [Date], City
```

See it work here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bebc4/4/0